# Trouble creating a virtual environment anaconda

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, kivy

So I am sort of new to programming and I am trying to setup a virtual environment for my IDE. I'm creating the environment through anaconada and a few of my packages are causing me trouble when I try to install them.

When I run:

```
(environment_name) C:\Users\Me>conda install -c krisvanneste kivy
```

I get this error message:
    Solving environment: failed

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - cantera
  - kivy
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

And if I run:`conda info kivy` nothing happens.

Also, when I run a simple Kivy script in Pycharm I get this error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\combustion13\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-05-31_20.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\combustion13\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\erad136env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\combustion13\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\erad136env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\combustion13\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\erad136env\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "C:\Users\combustion13\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\erad136env\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "C:\Users\combustion13\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\erad136env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: What happens if you try `venv`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html?highlight=venv#module-venv

Comment: Would I have to first deactivate the environment I am currently in?

Comment: not necessarily. You can create a new one from scratch. The thing is that most likely the package you're trying to install is conflicting with another package. So you might want to create a new virtual environment and install only what you need.

Comment: The error message means a conflict between `cantera` and `kivy`, so you should either uninstall `cantera` or create a new environment for `kivy`. no need to use `venv`, a conda environment will do. You should not mix `venv` and `conda`